# Proper usage of the word “conducive” in some constructions

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, linguistics

The most common and non-problematic use of this word is followed by “to” and a specific result, in a sentence like this:

> This environment is not conducive to good sleep.

However, some other uses I’ve come across have left me wondering:

> The atmosphere was conducive.

> The events were conducive to the economy.

Are these examples using the word correctly? Can conducive on its own be synonymous with productive or favorable (without an object)?

Also, I’m interested in the formal reason why we can say “conducive to good behavior” and not “conducive to behavior”. Can we say “conducive to work” or do we need to specify and say something like “quality work”?

I am trying to wrap my head around this both intuitively and formally - linguistically, so any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The atmosphere was conducive" is fine if you know from context what it's conducive to. Without a context, it's harder to understand. For example. "I wanted to work, but the atmosphere wasn't conducive" = "conducive to work". (As an aside, what do you think "conducive to behaviour" would mean if you did encounter it? If by "behaviour" you mean "good behaviour" it would be fine.)

Comment: Is "The events were conducive to the economy" (and your other examples) made up by you or do they have a source? I can't find any Google hits for that sentence, although "conducive to the economy" has plenty of Google results.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conducive) has a range of examples of "conducive to". Maybe you could consider which you consider to be acceptable.

Comment: “Conducive to the economy” is what a non-native speaker at work used and what made me start thinking about this. I searched “conducive” on Twitter and the first result was “this is not conducive to the conversation”. So either people are using it wrong or I’m misunderstanding the verb. I found “conducive environment” (without context) on Collins dictionary. Seems like an overall misunderstood and misused word?

Comment: As for behavior, I am aware it doesn’t mean anything, I was just looking for formal grammatical arguments as to why it doesn’t work. How would we define what type of noun needs to complete “conducive to”?

Comment: You will also find the verb **conduces to** in older texts.

Answer (score 1):

Though [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conducive) has the caveat

*Notice that conducive is almost always followed by **to**.*

its first example sentence is

> - *Air-conditioner cooling towers on the roof provided a conducive summertime abode, from which the germs circulated throughout the
>   edifice in a fine infectious mist.* —Wayne Biddle, A Field Guide to
>   Germs, 1995

The meaning must be 'suitable', 'facilitative', 'productive'.

[The Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development, OECD,](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/sites/7a712135-en/index.html?itemId=/content/component/7a712135-en) has:

> - *Ensuring a conducive policy context*

From [White Rose Research Online](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/160667/):

> - *A conducive environment? The role of need support in the higher education workplace and its effect on academics’ experiences of
>   research assessment in the UK.*

And [Science Direct, Volume 80, March 2023; Termansen et al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1353829223000333) has (using 'for'):

> - *Spaces of participation: Exploring the characteristics of conducive environments for citizen participation in a community-based health
>   promotion initiative in a disadvantaged neighborhood.*

But it would be silly not to have *some* context explaining *what* 'it' is suitable for, *what* it encourages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider that your examples are using the word correctly. It means *making something likely to happen* (not *something good*).

So if something is conducive to work, it encourages people to work, but not specifically to do *good* work.